# Prefill text fields with text in users language

Tags: trigger, translation

We are currently using text fields with default text to create a form for users when they create a new record, e.g.
custom_field_1 is not editable by any profiles and has default text that appears on creation saying "please rate your training:" and below is a picklist field.

Now we want to translate the text in custom_field_1 so that it matches that language of the user.
We can't continue to use the default text option because it exceeds the char limit. We can't use translation workbench because it isn't the field name itself but the text that would usually be entered by the user. If this requires a trigger, could you point me towards similar ones?

Comment: You should try using a `Before Save Flow` that sets the value to the correct API Name of the picklist entry you want. Your criteria would just check that the field is empty. This approach would allow you to use `Translation Workbench` if it works.